# How to let user select the number of loops for AVAudioPlayer playing audio

Tags: iphone, ios6, avaudioplayer

I am using AVAudioPlayer to play AudioFile.Now sometimes user wants to set repetition of the audio file. So how can i provide user this option to set number of loops to play audio file.

Thanks for help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5236913/whats-the-simplest-way-to-play-a-looping-sound

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the Property numberOfLoops to -1 and it would go into infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks for your help but i want user to set number of repetition on its own. I want user to have this control.

Comment: Yeah, you can use the UIPickerView to select no of loop to play.